# rspec/capybara <li> not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to test my AJAX with Rspec/Capybara.

My page (recruiter#dashboard) contains 3 columns.

It loads in candidates that applied for a certain vacancy and their state.

Column 1 => state==pending

Column 2 => state==matched

Column 3 ==> state=="sealed"

In my spec I'm creating a vacancy with 1 applicant that has state pending.

```
print "Amount of vacancies => #{Vacancy.count} "
print "Amount of candidates => #{Employee.count} "
print "Amount of candidates applied for vacancy => #{Matching.where(vacancy_id: Vacancy.first.id).count}"
print "State of #{Employee.first.name} for #{Vacancy.first.name} => #{Matching.where(vacancy_id: Vacancy.first.id, employee_id: Employee.first.id).first.state}"
```

returns

```
Amount of vacancies => 1
Amount of candidates => 1
Amount of candidates applied for vacancy => 1
State of foo1 Hintz for vacancy1 => pending
```

So that would mean that this candidate should be loaded in the li below:

```
<ul id="applied-desktop-dashboard-ajax">
  <li>
    CANDIDATES
  </li>
</ul>
```

Yet, when I run my test:

```
page.all("#applied-desktop-dashboard-ajax li").count.should eql(1)
```

returns

```
expected: 1
got: 0
```

When I

```
 save_and_open_page
```

I see the li is empty.

So I tried

```
sleep(5)
```

after

```
visit "dashboard"
```

But no success.

Does anyone have an idea why my li aren't loading in this test (but are working on localhost just fine.)?

Full test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Creating vacancies" do

  before do
    create(:matching)
  end

  scenario "Ajax testing" do
    visit "/recruiters/sign_in"
    fill_in "Email", with: "bedrijf1@hotmail.be"
    fill_in "Password", with: "bedrijf1bedrijf1"

    within 'form#new_recruiter' do
      find('input[name="commit"]').click
    end

    expect(current_path).to eq '/'

    visit "/dashboard"

    sleep(5)



    print "Amount of vacancies => #{Vacancy.count} "
    print "Amount of candidates => #{Employee.count} "
    print "Amount of candidates applied for vacancy => #{Matching.where(vacancy_id: Vacancy.first.id).count}"
    print "State of #{Employee.first.name} for #{Vacancy.first.name} => #{Matching.where(vacancy_id: Vacancy.first.id, employee_id: Employee.first.id).first.state}"

    # save_and_open_page
    page.all("#applied-desktop-dashboard-ajax li").count.should eql(1)

  end
end
```

Comment: Which driver are you using with capybara?  You might need to pass `js: true` to your scenario to get it to use the javascript driver.

Comment: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara

Comment: I added the js: true, this prompted me to install selenium and install firefox, which I did. Now it runs, but stops at the login screen where it fails to log in.
Is it using the same user that is being created at the start? I still see the user when I do puts "#{Recruiter.first.email}" but somehow when I login it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

When performing js tests the app being tested runs in a different thread than the test, which means they no longer share the same database connection - see https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup.  Because of this you need to disable transactional testing and use truncation or deletion to manage the database state.  The easiest way to do that is to use database_cleaner and setup a config that will swap to the needed strategy for each test - https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example

Once you have that configured correctly then it's time to look at your test and make it less brittle with asynchronous testing.

1. `expect(current_path).to eq '/'` should be rewritten as `expect(page).to have_current_path('/')`  so that Capybara will automatically wait for the page to change.
2. By default page.all doesn't wait for any elements to appear since 0 elements is a valid return.  If you change `page.all("#applied-desktop-dashboard-ajax li").count.should eql(1)` to `expect(page).to have_selector("#applied-desktop-dashboard-ajax li", count: 1)` Capybara will wait for a little bit of time for the li to appear on the page rather than failing immediately because the ajax hadn't yet completed.  You can also specify :minimum, :maximum, :between depending on what exactly you're verifying

Using the correct Capybara methods can remove the need for most if not all sleep()s in your testing.